# jquery drag n drop, not allow drop on clone drop container

Tags: javascript, jquery

try to drag item and drop to clone div, but it's not working. it's seem like jquery drag n drop not allow to drop on clone item.

drag n drop working on first one, after i click add more dropzone, and try to drop item to new dropzone. it's not allow to.

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brue35wd/17/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_dropzone", function(e){
$('<div class=\"dropzone\"></div>').insertAfter($('.dropzone').last());});

$( "ul li" ).each(function(){
    $(this).draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
});

$( ".dropzone" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "active",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            tolerance: "touch", 
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );

        if($(ui.draggable).hasClass('draggable-source'))
            $( ui.draggable ).clone().appendTo( this ).removeClass('draggable-source');


        else

            $( ui.draggable ).appendTo( this );

            $('.delete').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent('li').remove();
        });
        //alert($(this).text());
    }

}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
    }
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It drags. I can drag multiple items, too.

Comment: Like Josan said, it works fine.

Comment: yes, on first one it's working fine, after click on add dropzone, the dropzone after first one won't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/brue35wd/18/)

I have moved the initializing code to a function

Final code will look like

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_dropzone", function (e) {
    $('<div class=\"dropzone\"></div>').insertAfter($('.dropzone').last());
    initDroppable();
});

$("ul li").each(function () {
    $(this).draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
});
initDroppable();

function initDroppable() {
    if (typeof window.dropElem != "undefined") window.dropElem.droppable('destroy');
    window.dropElem = $(".dropzone").droppable({
        activeClass: "active",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        tolerance: "touch",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

            if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('draggable-source')) $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this).removeClass('draggable-source');


            else $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);

            $('.delete').on('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent('li').remove();
            });
            //alert($(this).text());
        }

    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
}
```